# What is difference between "com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration=false" and "jaxb.fragment=true"?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, marshalling

Recently when i worked with JAXB i had to remove xml header from generated file. I mean, i had to remove first line in xml file which looks like in this way:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

After few minutes i found on internet, that i can use one of this solution:

```java
marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.fragment", true);
```

or

```java
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", false);
```

Both worked for me... but what is difference between them?

**NOTE:** I'm using Java 12

I created a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can be found here https://github.com/starwarsjk/jaxb-remove-xml-header

Answer (score 1):

"com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration" is from JAXB 1 but still supported in JAXB 2. 
Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT is equivalent but preferred going forward.

Comment: Thank you @charlb!

But do you have any sources to your response?
I also found in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html) that if I'm using method 

`marshaller.marshal(Object, Writer);`
then the Marshaller won't generate an xml declaration.

Comment: See XML Declaration Control section in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/vendorProperties.html